# Por que o import do Jquery UI na página não funciona?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Não estou conseguinte ter acesso ao tema do Jquery IU na minha página HTML. Presumo que quando criar um botão e um menu, ele já me mostre no layout do tema, no qual baixei os arquivos, mas não funciona. Ele mostra o layout de um botão e de um menu comum. Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<html>

<head>
<link href="/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/external/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/jquery-ui-1.11.4.custom/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#IDdaDiv")
            .button()
            .click(function(){
                $("#dialog").dialog();
            })
    });
</script>


</head>

<body>



    <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="main.php" target="_self">Página Inicial</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Gestão de Pessoas</a>
            <ul class="listasubmenu">
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Colaboradores</a></li>
                <ul class="sub-submenu">
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Inclusão</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Editar</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Histórico</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Capacitações</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_self">Documentos</a></li>
                    </ul>
            </ul>
           </li>
           <li><a href="#" target="_self">Consulta</a>
            <ul class="listasubmenu">

            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" target="_self">Relatórios</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="# target="_parent">Sair</a></li>
    </ul>





   <button>A button element</button>

   </body>

   </html>
```

Comment: você já consultou a [documentação](https://jqueryui.com/)?

Comment: Os caminhos para os arquivos de css e js estão corretos? Quando vc acessa o código fonte na página, consegue acessar os arquivos css e js?

Comment: O jquery ui, possui estrutura CDN (online) e a estrutura local, é importante, saber a procedência desses arquivos, senão não irá funcionar mesmo.

Comment: Pelo que parece você esta importando mais de uma versão do Jquery, isso da conflito.

Comment: Sim os caminhos estão corretos. Na própria IDE quando ponho o '/' ele já me mostra os arquivos na pasta.

Comment: Como assim CDN? Poderia explicar melhor, por favor?